# How to fix ValueError while trying to add column using .append() in 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

While trying to add column at end of the 2D array using `.append()` gives `ValueError`.

Here's the Code:

```
import numpy as np 

twoDArray = np.array([[11, 15, 10, 6], [10, 14, 11, 5], [12, 17, 12, 8], [15, 18, 14, 9] ])


new2Darray1 = np.append(twoDArray, [[5, 6, 7, 8]], axis=1)
print("2D array after column insertion:")
print(new2Darray1)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?  This use of `np.append` is just `np.concatenate((A,B), axis=1)`.  A (4,4) can be joined to a (1,4) on axis 0, producing a (5,4).

Comment: Not pretty but it gets the job done `new2Darray1 = np.array([i for i in twoDArray] + [[5, 6, 7, 8]])`

Comment: You should re-read the documentation and make sure you understand how the `axis` parameter works.

Comment: What do you want?  (5,4) is easy with what you give.  (4,5) requires a transpose, (4,8) requires some replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way

```
import numpy as np 

twoDArray = np.array([[11, 15, 10, 6], [10, 14, 11, 5], [12, 17, 12, 8], [15, 18, 14, 9] ])

x=np.array([[5,6, 7, 8]])
new2Darray1 = np.append(twoDArray, x.T, axis=1)
print("2D array after column insertion:")
print(new2Darray1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a (4,4) array. If you want to append another row of 4 elements, you must choose `axis=0` (add along the rows).

So:

```
new2Darray1 = np.append(twoDArray, [[5, 6, 7, 8]], axis= 0)
```